# Javascript - Click outside of element using event.target not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a a pop up menu which has a close button that works fine. I'm also trying to close the menu when a user clicks outside of the box too.

I have tried using an if statement inside closeMenu() which checks if the event.target wasn't the button element but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas or direction is appreciated.

```
var button = document.createElement('DIV');
button.className = "DoorSelector--FamilyOption";
var event_func = (parent == null) ? this.closeMenu.bind(this, close_container) : this.createMenuOptions.bind(this, parent, null);
button.addEventListener('click', event_func);

Menu.prototype.closeMenu = function(container, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    container.classList.remove('show');
};
```

The full code can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/1XASpMvp) if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add your click-listener on `button`. Callback function `closeMenu` will invoke only if button is clicked, so if you click outside nothing happens. You should add event listener on "outside" :) On `<body>` for example